# Is there a difference between @var = var_val and self.send("var=", var_val)?

Tags: ruby

When I initialize instance variables in the initialize method, is there a difference between using `@var = var_value` and `self.send("var=", var_value)`? By this I mean, is there any reason to prefer one way over the other for any reason, even if that means a style reason?

```
class MySuperClass
  attr_accessor :columns, :options
end

class MySubClass < MySuperClass
  def initialize(columns, options)
    @columns = columns
    @options = options
  end
end

class MyOtherSubClass < MySuperClass
  def initialize(columns, options)
    self.send("columns=", columns)
    self.send("options=", options)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference.

`@var = x` assigns to an instance variable. There is no method call. There is no virtual dispatch. There is no (sane) way of intercepting the assignment.

`send` *invokes a method* (or "sends a message"). In context, `:var=` is the assessor "setter method" which *wraps* an instance variable assignment. But it's a method, is invoked via virtual dispatch honoring inheritance, and could do anything - including being overridden in subtypes.

The true equivalent to `@var = x` would be [instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set):

```
self.instance_variable_set(:@var, x)
```

---

Using `send` in this case is odd. Use the accessor directly (`self.columns = columns`) if that is the intent.

As to which one is "more correct" depends on the level of encapsulation established - and the contracts defined on the types and usages thereof. I generally err on the side of the accessors when subtypes are involved.

Comment: I'd say even using `instance_variable_set` is odd in this case, as it is used only when the first parameter is dynamic, i.e. evaluated during the course of program.

Comment: @MladenJablanović Yes, both are odd :) It was strictly to differentiate the operation.